# Regression trees to model rates

Tags: r, cart, rpart, offset

I am performing a predictive modeling application where I have to predict claims. If I had used classical GLMs, I would have used a poisson glm using log exposure as offset, assuming therefore $$\text{claims} = \text{exposure} \cdot \exp \left( x^T \beta \right),$$ assuming that claims are proportional to the exposure and therefore allowing for covariate dependency. I want to use ctree or rpart or other tree based approaches. Is it possible to handle prior offset in such models in some way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to adopt a formal model-based tree. The `glmtree()` function in the `partykit` package implements the general MOB algorithm for model-based recursive partitioning (Zeileis *et al.* 2008, *Journal of Computational and Graphical Statistics*, **17**(2), 492-514). This supports Poisson responses and also allows for the inclusion of offsets. Furthermore, additional regressors could be included in each of the terminal nodes.

Consider the following simple artificial example:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(
  x1 = runif(500),
  x2 = runif(500),
  exposure = runif(500, 1, 10)
)
d$claims <- rpois(500, lambda = exp(d$x1 > 0.5 & d$x2 > 0.5) * d$exposure)
```

This uses two simple partitioning variables (`x1` and `x2`) and an `exposure` variable. The response is Poisson-distributed with offset `log(exposure)` and mean `1 = exp(0)` except for the case when both `x1 > 0.5 & x2 > 0.5` where the mean is `exp(1)`

Then `glmtree()` can fit a Poisson GLM-based tree for `claims` with `offset(log(exposure))` and partitioning variables `x1 + x2`.

```
m <- glmtree(claims ~ offset(log(exposure)) | x1 + x2,
  data = d, family = poisson)
plot(as.constparty(m))
```

[image]

This captures the true tree structure (which is admittedly easy to find here) and correctly estimates the intercepts (with the default log-link):

```
coef(m)

##            2            4            5 
## -0.047934373 -0.005690107  1.050569309
```

You can also obtain more detailed information about each fitted GLM in the nodes of the tree, e.g., for the last node:

```
summary(m, node = 5)

## Call:
## glm(formula = claims ~ offset(log(exposure)))
## 
## Deviance Residuals: 
##      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
## -3.13527  -0.66977  -0.04251   0.56984   2.13581  
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)  1.05057    0.02375   44.24   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)
## 
##     Null deviance: 630.95  on 120  degrees of freedom
## Residual deviance: 113.36  on 120  degrees of freedom
## AIC: 635.89
## 
## Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

More details and references are provided in `vignette("mob", package = "partykit")`.