# Is "vanilla" random forest regression appropriate when dependent variable is a rate (i.e. per 100 people)?

Tags: random-forest, poisson-regression, offset, dependent-variable

To add a little more context, I am working with a dataset from which I want to predict the population-normalized count of emergency department visits on county level, with 50+ independent variables. The dataset itself contains raw counts of the ED visits, as well as the county populations, so I have a bit of freedom in terms of how I perform the normalization.

I am really struggling to determine an appropriate methodology to analyze this now, however. I know with more traditional generalized linear models, careful attention needs to be given to the distribution of the dependent variable. I assume the best way to do this in a general circumstance would be a Poisson regression with an offset, though I do not know how this translates to tree-based ML methodologies, which I am specifically interested in.

With this in mind, would a "vanilla" random forest regressor (or gradient boosting, alternatively) be appropriate to use here without giving these details too much thought? I have done some digging online for an answer to this, with mixed results. I've seen that sklearn has different criterion parameters - such as Poisson - when implementing an RF, but I don't know if that is really what I need. Would regular squared error still work?

Also, as a side note, part of my analysis intends to assess a random forest/gradient boosting methodology, specifically, for this application - which is why I would prefer not to use a different type of model if I can get away with it.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138395/regression-trees-to-model-rates

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a count data regression model, if only as a baseline. Then, in place of calculating rates, you model the counts and use (log of) county population as an offset.

These ideas can be used also with trees and forests. See the page [how-to-handle-the-exposure-offset-with-boosted-trees](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-the-exposure-offset-with-boosted-trees-fd09cc946837). There is an R implementation in CRAN package `partykit`, see function `glmtree`.  There is more information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037995/r-partykit-how-do-i-use-the-offset